# My first cin is ignored, it only accepts the second one

Tags: c++, cin

Alright so I got a simple code here:
(Enter number between 0-100 if cin is not a varable then clear cin, ignore the error line)

```
void Numbrs(int v1)
{
do
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
    cin >> v1;
    if (!(cin >> v1))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, please try again." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore (numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else
    {
        if (v1 < 0 || v1 > 100)
        {
            cout << "Invalid number, please try again." << endl;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
} while (v1 < 0 || v1 > 100);
}
```

(Of course its not doing anything now, because I'm going crazy its not working)
My problem with this is when I enter ANY number it always ignores the first one, here's an example:

```
Please enter a number between 0 and 100
111
315
Invalid number, please try again.
Please enter a number between 0 and 100
50
40
```

Could anybody explain why is this happening? It happens to me almost every time when I try to use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore (numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.

Comment: Did you mean to have a reference parameter to see the output in the calling function: `void Numbrs(int& v1)`?

Comment: Why the double `cin >> v1`? That is plain fishy!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are repeating the input operation:

```
cin >> v1; // Try removing this line
if (!(cin >> v1)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Wait, "if (!(cin >> v1))" actually asks for the input??
I though it was for checking if the input matches v1 which in this case is a variable... So then I dont need the "cin >> v1"? Or is there any other way to make an if statement check if my input has an error? (like giving a string as a variable)

Comment: You can check the input stream for errors with `if (! cin)`.

`(cin >> v1)` is an input statement. Its value is exactly `cin` after the operation, which is testable in boolean contexts.

Comment: Relevant references:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool